# rails action text about text and picture display on different location

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use rails develop blog use Avtion Text

create and show is successful.

---

```
def  show
    require "image_processing/mini_magick"
    @comment=PostComment.new
    @comments=@post.post_comments.includes(:post).order(id: :desc)
    
  end

  def create

    @post=current_user.posts.new(@clear_params)
    if @post.save
     redirect_to root_path
    else
       render :new   
    end
  end
```

---

In the home page ,I want list each article

1. I need get article first picture how can i do?
2. I want show only text how can i do? I try to use "to_plain_text" but keep show picture name
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHDqX.png)

Comment: in the index page
   <%= post.content.to_plain_text.squish%>

Answer (score 0):

question 2 I use  <%= sanitize_action_text_content(post.content.body)%> solve
now I hope get first picture place the content nearby